# Possible to write a text file (or some other file) in a docker container but access it when container has stopped?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to write a text file in a docker container such  that I can access the text file when the container is no longer running?

Comment: Do you mean something like [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, a short example, on my host I create a directory

`$ mkdir /tmp/mytest`

Then I launch a container bind mounting this directory

`$ docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/mytest:/tmp/mytest ubuntu bash`

Then I create a file in the container

`root@af7f784df77d:/# touch /tmp/mytest/zzzz1234`

I quit the container

`# exit`

My file, created inside the container, is still here on my host

`$ ls /tmp/mytest
zzzz1234`

You should read the doc provided by zero323